# Change character used for separation of form input fields with same name identifier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form which has a bunch of checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="input1" value="A, and B"/>A, and B
<input type="checkbox" name="input1" value="C"/>C
```

I also have some JQuery code that populates the already selected fields using JSTL like this:

```
$('input[name="input1"]').val("${form_inputs}".split(','));
```

The thing is since the value "A, and B" contains a comma, the jquery is splitting and setting the checkbox checked states wrong.

I already tried adding more commas so I could split at ",," but it doesnt seem to want to work.

Is there any way to change the comma splitter character to a different character?

Comment: Can you please provide an example object that you are trying to split `${form_inputs}`?

Comment: Why does your value need to have that string including a comma? You only see that value once you submit the form and the value is checked. So you can name the value whatever you want, because you know which checkbox it is through its name.

Comment: I agree with @Shilly we would advise you to change value if it is possible

Comment: The values im getting are from a database, I cant remove the commas. Also the ${form_inputs} would be the inputs of the previous submission of this form iff the form was not valid / completed properly. I need to re-send the form values so the user doesnt need to fill out the entire form again.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are getting such kind of object `['A, and B', 'C']` when you are trying to split `${form_inputs}`? Or maybe just string `'A, and B, C'`? If you don't know you can easily debug this variable using dev tools

Comment: The ${form_inputs} are a string of all the selected checkboxes concatenated. For exmaple if i selected both checkboxes the string would be as you said: "A, and B, C" . I forgot to mention before that im using Java spring web flow as a framework, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. As per [jQuery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/) you can't set checkbox value, only apply attribute `checked`. So in this situation you have to set value using such approach:

```js
$('input[name="input1"][value="A, and B"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="input1" value="A, and B"/>A, and B
<input type="checkbox" name="input1" value="C"/>C
```

UPDATE:

```js
const res = 'A, and B, C';
const sp = res.split(',');
let a = [];
 sp.forEach(el => {
  if(el.trim().length > 1){
   a[a.length-1] = a[a.length-1] + ', ' + el.trim();
  }else{
   a.push(el.trim());
  }
 });

a.forEach(function(el){
 $('input[name="input1"][value="'+el+'"]').prop('checked', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="input1" value="A, and B"/>A, and B
<input type="checkbox" name="input1" value="C"/>C
```

I've prepared updated answer which met your requirements, but you have to understand that this is a clear hack. I would strongly suggest you to rework your functionality to gain correct array from your variable.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me. Im not sure why but the .val seems to be working atm, checkboxes with values that do not contain a comma are populated properly. But I definitely agree that this is a better way and will change to this method.